# Box2d Collision. object gets deformed

Tags: c++, android, android-ndk, box2d, game-physics

i'm developing an app that uses Box2d. i have a world with several blocks and an object that
collides with them. at the moment the collision starts, the objects start to change their shape, they get more large. what could be causing that.

i'm creating the bodies in fixed positions and in sleep state. also shapeDef->friction = 0.8f;
shapeDef->density = 1.0f; shapeDef->restitution = 0.2f;

maybe i'm not using the right physics parameters, i don't want that deformation. just the movement and the body keeping its original form.

Comment: they shouldn't be deformed at all....something screwy is going on. you sure they're changing their shape, not just overlapping or something? is your drawing routine correct?

Comment: i'm checking my drawing function, i'm using opengl es calls to set the vertices taken from the b2shape when is created. and when drawing i use glTranslatef and glRotatef to update the position and rotation that the b2Body haves.

Answer (score 1):

OK i found the bug.

it's fault of my rendering function. the aspect ratio in the gl initialization wasn't correct, so when the object was rotating on the axis it was being enlarged.